# SVN commit Error

Tags: svn

I am able to do SVN update, but when I do SVN commit it throws the error below:

```
Error:  Commit Failed (details follow):
Error:  Can't read from connection:  An existing connection was forcibly closed by the     
Error:  remote host
```

After this I can't even browse my repository from Visual SVN.  It throws an error saying

```
Can't connect to host 'ddev':  No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

I have to restart Subversion Server to browse and update.... but CAN'T commit.

Where should I look into ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the symptoms you've described, it sounds like your Subversion server is crashing when you try to commit (that's why you can't browse the repo after getting the first error). Have a look at the server logs to see if you can find out why.

Comment: In server logs it says Faulting application svnserve.exe, version 1.6.6.40053, time stamp 0x4ae657f2, faulting module libapr-1.dll, version 1.3.3.0, time stamp 0x4a0b673e, exception code 0xc0000005, fault offset 0x000120a2, process id 0x36c, application start time 0x01cbf578f3441f00.

Comment: Well, that confirms that it *is* the svnserve.exe that is crashing. It's hard to say where to start looking from here...

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the post commit hooks first.